# Visual Studio 2012 Custom CompareTo Method slow when debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, compareto

I have a DataTable that I'm sorting ascending by 3 columns. Tricky part is that the column can contain numeric and non-numeric values. Because of that, we see if we can cast this field, if so, we do numeric compare, otherwise we do a string compare.

This works very good in compiled version, but in Visual Studio 2012 this goes extremly slow ... Some how the comparing takes more then 5 minutes in debugging mode, in compiled mode it takes less than a second.

I deleted all breakpoints, but still only this part of my code goes to slow in debugging mode.

The comparing code:

```
Public Function CompareValues(ByVal sThis As String, ByVal sOther As String) As Integer
    Dim bFirstNumeric As Boolean = IsNumeric(sThis)
    Dim bOtherNumeric As Boolean = IsNumeric(sOther)

    If bFirstNumeric AndAlso bOtherNumeric Then
        Return Integer.Parse(sThis).CompareTo(Integer.Parse(sOther))
    ElseIf bFirstNumeric And Not bOtherNumeric Then
        Return -1
    ElseIf Not bFirstNumeric And bOtherNumeric Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return sThis.CompareTo(sOther)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm sure it is an Integer. This is a system that was build only to be strings, but after years we had to add this functionality. Show Integer.TryParse be faster then IsNumeric?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the IsNumeric check like this and then proceed, from here. It is cleaner.

```
Dim Value1 As Object
Dim Value2 As Object
Dim V1 As Integer
Dim V2 As Integer

Public Function IsNumeric(ByVal Expression As Object) As Boolean

If IsNumeric(Value1) = True And IsNumeric(Value2) = True Then

    V1 = Integer.Parse(Value1)
    V2 = Integer.Parse(Value2)

End If

Return True

End Function
```

Let me know, if you need more help.

Comment: I do not really get why this would be cleaner. I'm using the -1,0,1 value for a BubbleSort system. But with this my main problem is not resolved: the slow debugging on this BubbleSort. If I do a Sort on an ArrayList (which used IComparable), I use the same function and also there my sort is extremely slow in debugging mode, compiled without debugger this goed really fast.